# invalid use of incomplete type / forward declaration

Tags: c++, gcc, forward-declaration, incomplete-type

I tried to look at the similar problems listed here on Stackoverflow and on Google but they deal mostly with templates and that's not my case. I'm using GCC 4.4.5 on Debian Testing 64bit.
So, I have two classes - CEntity:

```
#ifndef CENTITY_H_INCLUDED
#define CENTITY_H_INCLUDED

#include "global_includes.h"

// game
#include "CAnimation.h"
#include "Vars.h"
#include "vector2f.h"
#include "Utils.h"

class CAnimation;

class CEntity
{
public:
    CEntity();
    virtual ~CEntity();

    void _update(Uint32 dt);

    void updateAnimation(Uint32 dt);

    void addAnimation(const std::string& name, CAnimation* anim);
    void addAnimation(const std::string& name, const CAnimation& anim);
    void removeAnimation(const std::string& name);
    void clearAnimations();

    bool setAnimation(const std::string& name);

    SDL_Surface* getImage() const;

    const vector2f& getPos() const;
    const vector2f& getLastPos() const;
    F getX() const;
    F getY() const;
    F getLastX() const;
    F getLastY() const;
    SDL_Rect* getHitbox() const;
    SDL_Rect* getRect() const;

    F getXSpeed() const;
    F getYSpeed() const;

    void setPos(const vector2f& pos);
    void setPos(F x, F y);
    void setPos(F n);
    void setX(F x);
    void setY(F y);

    void setHitboxSize(int w, int h);
    void setHitboxSize(SDL_Rect* rect);
    void setHitboxWidth(int w);
    void setHitboxHeight(int h);

    void setSpeed(F xSpeed, F ySpeed);
    void setXSpeed(F xSpeed);
    void setYSpeed(F ySpeed);

    void stop();
    void stopX();
    void stopY();

    void affectByGravity(bool affect);

    void translate(const vector2f& offset);
    void translate(F x, F y);

    bool collide(CEntity& s);
    bool collide(CEntity* s);

protected:
    CAnimation* mCurrentAnimation;
    SDL_Surface* mImage;

    vector2f mPos;
    vector2f mLastPos;
    SDL_Rect* mHitbox; // used for collisions
    SDL_Rect* mRect; // used only for blitting

    F mXSpeed;
    F mYSpeed;

    bool mAffByGrav;

    int mHOffset;
    int mVOffset;

private:
    std::map<std::string, CAnimation*> mAnims;
};

#endif // CENTITY_H_INCLUDED
```

and CPlayerChar which inherits from CEntity:

```
#ifndef CPLAYERCHAR_H_INCLUDED
#define CPLAYERCHAR_H_INCLUDED

#include "global_includes.h"

// game
#include "CEntity.h"

class CEntity;

class CPlayerChar : public CEntity
{
public:
    CPlayerChar();
    virtual ~CPlayerChar();

    virtual void update(Uint32 dt) = 0;

    virtual void runLeft() = 0;
    virtual void runRight() = 0;
    virtual void stopRunLeft() = 0;
    virtual void stopRunRight() = 0;

    virtual void attack() = 0;
    virtual void stopAttack() = 0;

    virtual void attack2() = 0;
    virtual void stopAttack2() = 0;

    virtual void ground() = 0;
    virtual void midair() = 0;

    void jump();
    void stopJump();

protected:
    // looking right?
    bool mRight;

    bool mJumping;
    bool mOnGround;
    bool mGrounded;
};

#endif // CPLAYERCHAR_H_INCLUDED
```

When I try to compile it, GCC throws this error:

```
CPlayerChar.h:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct CEntity’
CPlayerChar.h:9: error: forward declaration of ‘struct CEntity’
```

I tried it first without the forward declaration 'class CEntity;' in CPlayerChar.h on line 9, but then it would throw this instead

```
CPlayerChar.h:12: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
```

So the forward declaration has to be there. Also, CEntity is clearly a class, not a struct.

Comment: In C++ classes and structs are almost identical; don't get hung up on the error message.

Comment: I presume that the class definition for `CEntity` is in the file `CEntity.h`? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: You have some circular inclusion in your header files. A header file should only include other header files if it explicitly needs too. If you can use a forward declaration then this should be preferred.

Answer (score 12):

You have a circular inclusion in your header files.
But without all the header files we will not be able to fix it.

I would start here.

```
#include "CAnimation.h"
```

Looking at your header you don't actually need this. You only use CAnimation by reference or pointer so the forward declaration you have should be sufficient. Move the include into the source file (ie out of the header).

The next place I would look is:

```
#include "global_includes.h"
```

Any global includes that are included in a header file better be very simple. Should only contain simple types and not include any other header files (unless they are just as simple). Anything complex is going to lead to problems with circular dependencies.

#### General rule of thumb

A header file should only include header files that it absolutely needs. Otherwise they should be included from the source file. You only absolutely need a header file if it defines a class that is used as a parent class you have members objects of that class, or you use parameter objects of that class.

I use the term `object` to distinguish from references or pointers. If you are using these you do not need to include the header file. You only need to do a forward declaration.

Comment: About the circular dependencies, if he has #ifndef CANIMATION_H_INCLUDED, shouldn't the issue be prevented?

Comment: @antogerva That helps but is not enough. You also need to forward declare types. Also only including headers you specifically need and forward declaring other types.

Answer (score 6):

You probably have got a loop in your includes in such way that CPlayerChar doesnt know who really is CEntity, it just knows that it exists, but doesnt know what is it.

If you remove the "class CEntity" declaration, you will see that GCC will complain that CEntity doesnt exists.

You must check that nothing that CEntity includes include CPlayerChar.

Comment: Thanks, that last line of yours must be it. CEntity includes another file which includes CEntity and CPlayerChar. Now I just need to find a workaround.

Answer (score 5):

You have to ensure that the full *definition* of the class `CEntity` is visible at the point where you define the class `CPlayerChar`. (So check your inclusions.)

This is because you can only inherit from fully defined classes, but not from just forward-declared ones.

The only time you can get away with forward-declarations in place of full definitions is when you make pointers or references to a type, but only if you never access any of its members, or (thanks to @Alf) when declaring a function with incomplete return type.

Comment: forward declarations are a bit more powerful than you appear to indicate. For example, if `T` is an incomplete type, then declaring a function `T foo()` is perfectly all right. In order to call it you need to have `T` completed (unless `T` is the special type `void`, which formally is an incomplete type that can never be completed), but that's a different issue. :-)

Comment: @Alf: Thanks! That's useful. What about function parameters, can those be incomplete?